# Python 2.7.2 doesn't properly iterate through logger's handlers

Tags: logging, python-2.7

the following code is very simple, but for some reason, for-loop does not iterate through all handlers of the logger. however, for-loop does iterate through all handlers if we remove **my_logger.removeHandler( handler )** in the else clause. any idea if I'm doing anything wrong?

```
import logging
import sys

stdf = logging.Formatter( "%(message)s" )
filef = logging.Formatter( "%(message)s" )
my_logger = logging.getLogger( "file std logger" )
stdh = logging.StreamHandler( sys.stdout )
stdh.setFormatter( stdf )
my_logger.addHandler( stdh )
fileh = logging.FileHandler( "run.log", mode = 'w', encoding = "utf-16-le", delay = True )
fileh.setLevel( logging.DEBUG )
fileh.setFormatter( filef )
my_logger.addHandler( fileh )

my_logger.info("wow1")
my_logger.info("test string1")
my_logger.info("wow2")
my_logger.info("test string2")
my_logger.info("wow3")
my_logger.info("test string3")

for handler in my_logger.handlers:
    print(handler)
    if handler.__class__.__name__ == "FileHandler":
        handler.flush()
        handler.close()
        my_logger.removeHandler( handler )
    else:
        handler.flush()
        my_logger.removeHandler( handler )

my_logger.handlers
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classic destructive iteration. What you are doing is:

```
>>> l= [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> for n in l:
...     l.remove(n)
... 
>>> l
[1, 3]
```

In this example only every second element is removed. Why? Well the `for`...`in` syntax obscures what's actually happening, which is the same as in a traditional C-style for-index loop:

```
>>> l= [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> i= 0
>>> while i<len(l):
...     del l[i]
...     i+= 1
...
>>> l
[1, 3]
```

So first time round the loop `i` is 0. Item 0 gets removed, moving items 1–4 down one place to be the new items 0–3. Next time round the loop `i` is `1` so the current item 1, which is `2`, is removed. The original `1` has been jumped and remains in the loop.

A simple workaround to avoid destructive iteration is to take a copy of the list and iterate the copy whilst changing the original:

```
for handler in list(my_logger.handlers):
```

Using `filter` or list comprehensions is typically a simpler route when you are trying to remove certain items from a list.

Comment: I thought iterator iterate through all elements at the point of time when we started the iterator. that means the tutorial that said "Python's for-loop is the same as C/C++" is wrong... This would mean modification of the list during the iteration is dangerous. This is different from C/C++ because C/C++ only delete the content pointed by the array pointer without removing the array pointers. thanks for pointing this out.