# Handling logger from imported module

Tags: python-3.x, python-logging

I am developing a package for which I wrote my own custom logger, and to it I am adding a `FileHandler` and a `StreamHandler`. This works fine and the stream logs and file logs are as desired. So far so good.

But now I import a certain external library, and as soon as I do that all my log statements start printing twice. Looking at the source of that library, I see that in one of its files it is doing

```
logging.basicConfig(level=log_level, format=format_string)
```

If I comment that, then my logging works fine again.

I don't have access to the source of this imported library, its external. What would be the right way to prevent this from happening?

Plus, in general, is it a bad practice to have a `logging.basicConfig(...)` if I am writing a module that could be imported by other libraries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that doing a `logging.basicConfig()` call in a module when not inside a

`if __name__ == '__main__'` context is generally bad manners.

That said, you can call `logging.basicConfig(..., force=True)` (or `logging.config.dictConfig()`) in your code and set your settings.  Your call will overwrite the settings in place.

You could also find out what "logger name" the offending module is using and override its logging level in your code.

`logging.getLogger("offending.modules.logger.name").setLevel("CRITICAL")`.

Comment: Thanks, though I am using a `StreamHandler` so I won't be able to call `logging.basicConfig(..., force=True)`. I guess I will try out the other things.

Comment: In that case you may remove the offending handler as in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7812263/python-2-7-2-doesnt-properly-iterate-through-loggers-handlers